# Вывод фото по названию php файла

Tags: php

Есть папка с фото ./img/mega_foto_2/

В этой папке находятся изображения:

```
acura_ilx_endurance_racer_2013_1.jpg
acura_ilx_endurance_racer_2013_2.jpg
acura_ilx_endurance_racer_2013_3.jpg
acura_ilx_endurance_racer_2013_4.jpg
.......
acura_nsx_2016_1.jpg
acura_nsx_2016_2.jpg
acura_nsx_2016_3.jpg
acura_nsx_2016_4.jpg
alfa_romeo_giulia_2016_1.jpg
alfa_romeo_giulia_2016_2.jpg
alfa_romeo_giulia_2016_3.jpg
alfa_romeo_giulia_2016_4.jpg
alfa_romeo_pandion_concept_2010_1.jpg
alfa_romeo_pandion_concept_2010_2.jpg
alfa_romeo_pandion_concept_2010_3.jpg
alfa_romeo_pandion_concept_2010_4.jpg
```

Например Файл называется acura_ilx_endurance_racer_2013.php

Как сделать вывод по названию файла? Например если файл acura_ilx_endurance_racer_2013.php, то вывести только фото с названием acura_ilx_endurance_racer_2013_1.jpg, acura_ilx_endurance_racer_2013_2.jpg  .....
acura_ilx_endurance_racer_2013_n.jpg

```
    <?php
    $directory = './img/mega_foto_2'; //название папки с изображениями
    $allowed_types=array('jpg','jpeg'); //разрешеные типы изображений
    $file_parts=array();
      $ext='';
      $title='';
      $i=0;
    //пробуем открыть папку
      $dir_handle = @opendir($directory) or die("There is an error with your image directory!");

      // имя файла PHP
    $php_filename = basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);
    // обрежем `.php`
    $php_filename = substr($php_filename, 0, -4);


$counter = 0; //заводим счетчик
for($i=0; $i<=(sizeof($php_filename)-1); $i++) {




    $files=array();
    while ($file = readdir($dir_handle))    //поиск по файлам
      {
      if($file=='.' || $file == '..') continue;
      array_push($files,$file);
      }
      sort($files);
      $stop = 3;
    foreach ($files as $file) {

    if (($srch = strripos($file, $php_filename)) !== FALSE) {
            echo '<div id="container"><img src="js/blank.gif" data-src="'.$directory.'/'.$file.'" /></div>';
            --$stop;
        }


$counter++; //увеличиваем счетчик на единичку
  }



        // если найдена третья картинка, то стоп
        if (!$stop) {
            break;
        } 
      $i++;  

        }
    closedir($dir_handle);  //закрыть папку

    ?>



 <?php 
echo $counter;
?>
```

Comment: Если я правильно понял ваш вопрос, то можно попробовать следующий способ. Берем название файла и название каждой картинки. С помощью функции `explode` разбиваем их на две части: до точки и после точки. Часть что после точки отбрасываем, а первую часть записываем в переменную отдельно для файла и картинки. После чего сравниваем вхождение название файла в название картинки с помощью функции `stripos`. Получается, что название картинки содержит в себе соответственное название файла и если совпадение найдено - то продолжаем дальше.

Comment: А как быть с ..._n   (..._n.jpg)?

Comment: Функция `stripos` возвращает позицию первого вхождения подстроки без учета регистра. То есть если мы сравним строки acura_ilx_endurance_racer_2013 и acura_ilx_endurance_racer_2013_1 - то она найдет вхождение первый строки во вторую и вернет 0 в данном случае, что значит - совпадение найдено с позиции 0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$images = array(
    'acura_ilx_endurance_racer_2013_1.jpg',
    'acura_ilx_endurance_racer_2013_2.jpg',
    'acura_ilx_endurance_racer_2013_3.jpg',
    'acura_ilx_endurance_racer_2013_4.jpg'
);

// имя файла PHP
$php_filename = basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);
// обрежем `.php`
$php_filename = substr($php_filename, 0, -4);

// искать третее вхождение нужно не по имени, а по порядку
$stop = 3;
foreach ($images as &$image) {
    // искать подстроку в строке
    if (($srch = strripos($image, $php_filename)) !== FALSE) {
        echo "<img src='$image'>\n";
        --$stop;
    }
    // если найдена третья картинка, то стоп
    if (!$stop) {
        break;
    }
}
unset($image);
```

Comment: Немного изменил код на более приемлимый. Не получается интегрировать ваш код в изменненный скрипт. Я что-то запутался. Прошу помочь! Неработает. Где может быть ошибка?

Comment: На каком месте прерывается выполнение? Вы же дебаггер уже освоили?

Comment: Так. Чуток подправил. Спасибо все работает. Ищет и выводит 3 фото. Если можете еще подсказать. Постоянно вывод происходит: img_1.jpg, img_10.jpg, а должно img_1.jpg, img_2.jpg...Почему так происходит? Там где скрипт - Измененный...

Comment: Использовал вместо sort функцию natcasesort - решение этой проблемы

Comment: если всё получилось, поправьте исходное сообщение-вопрос. чтоб случайно зашедший сюда посетитель мог разобраться, о чем шла речь, не читая простыню кода )

Comment: Все поправил. Подскажите правильно ли я интегрировал счетчик. Нужно посчитать не 3, а все файлы `php_filename`

Comment: Нет. Для того, чтобы посчитать все картинки нужно не прерывать цикл после трёх найденных картинок. Тогда перед  циклом `while` `$counter = 0`, в цикле `++$counter`. А чтобы находилось только три картинки, проверять перед `echo` значение `$stop <= 0`. Но не выходить из цикла, а просто не выводить картинки.